# what is `import m from '..';`

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, formatter

What does the line

```
import m from '..';
```

really means?

Source: [Here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-formatter-pretty/blob/master/test/test.js#L5)

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as

```
import m from '../index.js'
```

Comment: There's no m in index.js file.

Comment: The default export (module.exports) of index.js is named m here. You can name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's a default import from the parent folder. It's short for

```
import { default as m } from '../index.js';
```

(assuming [node.js rules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for resolving module paths) and refers to [this file](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-formatter-pretty/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: I think default import means not using the destructing of modules, which you are doing here, and what does that import from default?

Comment: @RahulGurung There is no destructuring (or destruction) in module imports. Whether you create the `m` alias with `import m from …` syntax or the longhand `import { default as m } from …` syntax doesn't matter. A default export is just a normal export with a special name, its not a "namespace object" thing.

Answer (score 1):

`..` mean the parent directory of that file, so the import should bring in all modules found in the parent directory, in this case that's importing `index.js`.

Comment: But it has not m, or it can be named anything?